# SQL Counting Rows Per Day - Firebird Database

Tags: sql, count, firebird

I am using a Firebird database to store Logs from an Web App.
Each logged step,is stored in a different row of this table.
Each Row have a Data (OADATE formatted,as a double).

My next step,is writing a report query,to select how many Logs were added per day.

My Question is : How do i make this query?

Just to clarify, my expected result would be something like this:

```
1-dec-2011 : 3 
2-dec-2011 : 1
5-dec-2011 : 8
```

And so on...
How do i do that?

I Just Tried :

```
select (extract (WeekDay from (cast (A.DATETIME as Date))))
from EVENTSGENERAL A
```

Also,tried to cast as Timestamp,but the convertion from double to Date or Timestamp is giving me errors.

Thanks in advance,let me know if you need any other information provided

===========================================

Comment: i'd say put that query into an "answer" and then mark that answer as the 'answer'. nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: I know,i just can´t yet.
I have to wait 8 hours before doing this,because of the reputation limitation created by StackOverflow.

I will move it to answer after this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CAST(A.DATETIME as DATE) as Day,count(*)
from EVENTSGENERAL A
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
Thats the query i used:

```
select ROUND(A.DATETIME) as Day,count(*)
from EVENTSGENERAL A
group by Day
```

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL use this query

```
select DATE_TRUNC('day', A.DATETIME) as Day,count(*)
from EVENTSGENERAL A
group by Day
```

More info on Date/Time function for PostgreSQL go to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-datetime.html